# TEXTJOIN buscando por entradas duplicadas e concatenando resultado na mesma celula

Tags: microsoft-excel

Preciso mostrar apenas os domínios que determinada conta faz parte.

Tentei de algumas formas com `TEXTJOIN`, `IF`, `INDEX`, e o máximo que cheguei foi no resultado abaixo, que ele acaba mostrando todo o array como resultado ao invés de apenas os domínios que essa conta existe.

Por outro lado, a linha buscando pelo usuário operator não mostra nada como resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui].

Alguém sabe como consigo este resultado?

```
=TEXTJOIN(";"; TRUE; IF(A2:A10=$E$2; B2:B10; ""))
```

Comment: Não entendi qual é o resultado esperado, poderia editar com o que você deseja que a fórmula realize?

Comment: Se o admin tiver mais de um domínio ele vai aparecer onde? Na coluna C? Na célula B3 e deslocar as demais para baixo?